# How to execute DOS command using java on SERVER side using Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, batch-file, command, dos

I am developing a Project on Google App Engine, which will execute DOS command on Server Side and mail it to specific user.
Here is a sample code which I am using to execute dos command using JAVA.

```
     package com.alex.coderjunction.server;

      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStreamReader;

      public class BatRunner {
     public String BatResult() throws IOException {
        StringBuffer sbOut=new StringBuffer();
        String cmd = "cmd /c ipconfig/all";
         Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
         Process pr = r.exec(cmd);
         BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader( pr.getInputStream() )); 
         String s ;
         while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
             sbOut.append(s+"\n"); 
           }
        return sbOut.toString(); 
    }
}
```

Whenever i runs it, I am getting error like this:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "<<ALL FILES>>" "execute")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:431)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.alex.coderjunction.server.BatRunner.BatResult(BatRunner.java:17)
    at com.alex.coderjunction.server.Mailer.sendMail(Mailer.java:37)
    ......
    .........
```

Well, i know it seems awkward, when i am trying to execute dos command remotely. But still any advice/solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to run ipconfig on appengine, for starters you can't run any shell/dos command and appengine isn't windows

Comment: @TimHoffman well I understand your point. Fact is that i can do this thing Locally but when i use Google SDK it gives error. All i want to know, if there is any probable way to execute dos commands on server side, while keeping them in server side code.

Comment: There isn't. Appengine SDK presents a sandbox close to what you will experience in production.  You just can't do it. Why don't you explain what you are trying to achieve with the shell command. There is probably a java lib or appengine service that can do the same thing, if not then what you want is not possible on appengine.

Comment: @TimHoffman Let us say i want to run "ipconfig/all" command on server side. Please tell me how is it possible

Comment: Its not and it doesn't make sense in appengine.  Google don't provide any means for you to examine the network interfaces.  How can this be useful in the context of an appengine based application.

Comment: There is no use case for appengine and this functionality.  If you want to run your own custom server/protocols consider using AWS or Google Compute Engine.  It's just not going to happen in appengine.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thanks for coming straight. Well, i was trying to build appspot site for my group, where if user after visiting clicks "Send" button on it, it will run "ipconfig" cmd(just like we do in local) and will mail me info.

Comment: This makes no sense in the appengine production environment.  Concentrate on what appengine does well, and you have a valuable service,

Answer (score 2):

The SDK attempts to emulate the evironment that apps get deployed to (i.e., appspot.com), so that you'll have reasonable confidence that what you see when you develop locally will be what you see once you deploy. Part of emulation involves disabling some facilities, such as starting processes. You can't start processes from a deployed app, therefore we prevent you from starting processes under dev_appserver.

The workaround, assuming this is something you'll only have working under dev_appserver, is to set up a seperate local server that will run a DOS command on demand, returning the result as a response. You can then connect to that server from your local app using either a socket or `URLFetch`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can run DOS shell commands server-side in GAE.

Ask yourself what is the underlying operating system that would execute the process? Unless I am very mistaken, it is probably not DOS.

Comment: Absolutely not DOS and such functionality I doesn't exist in appengine,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute any system command in Google App Engine. Especially Windows/DOS shell commands.
Read the description of the sandbox environment here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/